# How to find element using text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to hide the parent div based on child text content ?

```js
//$('div > .tree-title').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="tree-title">Hello</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span>2</span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="tree-title">World</span>
</div>
```

In this case I would like to hide the second div because the class `.tree-title` contain `World` text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```js
$('div > .tree-title:contains(World)').parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="tree-title">Hello</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span>2</span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="tree-title">World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer is there any equivalent using only css ?

Comment: @executable, I believe there is no equivalent of `:contains` in css:)

Comment: @executable no. There was discussion about adding `:content` to CSS, but it has been abandoned: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#content-selectors

Answer (score 2):

Using [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('div > .tree-title:contains("World")').parent().hide();
```

Using [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
$('.tree-title').contents().filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().trim() == 'World';
}).parents('container').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer is there any equivalent using only css ?

Comment: There's no parent selector in css so we cannot use purely from css.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) Selector

```js
$('div:has(.tree-title:contains(World))').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="tree-title">Hello</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span>2</span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="tree-title">World</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also:

```
$('.tree-title').each(function() {
  if($(this).text() === 'World') {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  }
});
```

Hope it helps :)